# How to manipulate the application configs for controller tests?

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework3, zend-test, controller-tests

I'm writing functional / controller tests for a ZF3 application (driven by PHPUnit and `zendframework/zend-test`). Like this:

```
public function testWhatEver()
{
    $this->dispatch('/');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);
}
```

It's working pretty well. But now I got a case, where I need to test the application with multiple mutually exclusive configs.

E.g., the case "authentication": The application provides multiple authentication methods (let's say: `AuthA`, `AuthB`,`AuthC`). (That is configurable via setting of the `auth.type`'s value in the config file.) I want to test each of them. That means, it's not enough to have special test configs in the `/config/autoload/test/*{local|global}.php`. I need to be able to manipulate them for every test (before I call the `dispatch(...)` method).

**How to manipulate the application configs for / from controller tests (on the fly)?**

---

If no better solution can be found, a possible workaround might be to edit the config file (by using `file_put_contents(...)` or something like this) before every test. But it's a bit ugly (and slow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I see no really nice solution for this problem. But there some more or less acceptable workaround:

**Workaround 1: manipulating the according config file for every test**

1. `$configs = file_get_contents(...)`
2. `searchByRegexAndManipulateConfigs(...)`
3. `file_put_contents(...)`

It's much effort and would make the testing slower (due to reading from / writing to the filesystem).

**Workaround 2: simple files with only one config value**

We can create files like `config.auth.type.php` or `config.auth.type.txt` (one per config value t keep the file really simple) and to use `inclue` or `file_get_contents(...)` call as value in the config. The the value in the file needs to be manipulated before the test execution.

It's a bit less effort (we don't need to write complex RegEx), but might make the test considerably slower, since *every* application request would start by reading an additional file.

**Workaround 3: passing configs values through `GLOBALS`**

It's the simplest and fastest variant. We just save the needed value into a global variable and read it in the config (file's) array. After the test we remove the variable:

**`AuthBTest`**

```
...
protected function setUp() // or setUpBeforeClass()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $GLOBALS['appTestConfigs']['auth.type'] = 'AuthA';
}

protected function tearDown() // or tearDownAfterClass()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    unset($GLOBALS['appTestConfigs']);
}
...
```

**`/config/autoload/test/local.php`**

```
return [
    'auth' => [
        'type' => isset($GLOBALS['appTestConfigs']['auth.type']) ? $GLOBALS['appTestConfigs']['auth.type'] : 'AuthA',
    ],
];
```